# Fluent Validation not working as expected with .Equal() test

Tags: c#, post, model, fluentvalidation

I have created a FluentValidation (FV) test for a customer view model.
 in the model the test is:

```
{RuleFor(x => x.Email).NotNull().EmailAddress().WithMessage("Email format is Invalid").DependentRules(() => {
            RuleFor(x => x.EmailExists).Equal(1).WithMessage("Email is already in use!");                
        });
```

So what is meant to happen is that the email is tested to ensure its not null and is a real email format. Then if this test is passed the dependent rule checks another field to ensure that the email does not already exist in the AspNetUsers table. I did this by making a test during the page POST method, before passing the model to the validator for checking, like this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Email))
{
    var exists = _userService.UserExists(model.Email);
    model.EmailExists = exists ? 1 : 0;
}

CustomerAddViewModelValidator validator = new CustomerAddViewModelValidator();    
ValidationResult result = validator.Validate(model);

if (!result.IsValid) 
{
    model.ListTitles = GetTitlesList();              
    return View(model);
}
```

So far so good. The initial test for the Email is working and it drops into the dependent check, this is where its behaviour goes weird:

The behaviour is: 
If I use: `RuleFor(x => x.EmailExists).Equal(1)` FV always reports as if the email already exists,
even if the email doesn't

If I use  `RuleFor(x => x.EmailExists).Equal(0)` FV always reports as if the email does not exist and no warning is given, even if the email input does exist.

Initally I was doing this test on a HiddenFor field but after reading about JS unobtrusive validation I made EmailExists a label on the Razor Web page, until I can figure out why its not reporting the correct state.

[image: non existen email shows message when it shouldnt]

and when the email exists:

[image]

So you can see that the FV rule is reporting the same message whatever the result (0 or 1) is.

Can any help? I have tried using a boolean with much the same results. All my other validation works successfully so I think I may not be using the correct check?

As always, thanks in advance.

this is the rendered code:

[image]

and here is the screen shot:

[image]

and here is the amended RuleFor:

`RuleFor(x => x.Email).NotNull().EmailAddress().WithMessage("Email format is Invalid").DependentRules(() => {
    RuleFor(x => x.EmailExists).Equal(0).WithMessage("Email is already in use!");
});`

as you can see, the rule is correct but I get the SAME BEHAVIOUR WHERE THE  RESULT IS 1 or ) and whether the email exists or not..:

[image]

Comment: Have you debugged your code to make sure `exists` actually is what you think it is?

Comment: Hi @JuanR yes, I create the `Exists` value in the POST controller method, before testing the model with FV. The 0 and 1 in the images I have displayed is the value for `Exists` being passed to the Validation class and the view when the validation fails.

Comment: I understand that, but have you actually debugged to verify that `exists` is false? I know it sounds silly but sometimes we assume things.

Comment: Hi Juan, yes like I said in my question, you can see the actual value of EXISTS in the label below the email address in the images I posted. I am doing the test to check if the user exists as the first thing that happens in the POST method, then I update the model accordingly and then call Fluent Validation.

Comment: I think the issue has to do with how you are populating the `EmailExists` property. Rather than trying to get this to work, I would recommend you read this post which essentially describes a pattern to achieve what you are looking to do (validate unique email address as part of the process): https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/remote-client-side-validation-with-fluentvalidation/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lay with me trying to affect the model in the POST method, BEFORE calling the FluentValidation validator for the Customer model. Altho it appeared that I could update the model, and see it updated in the IDE while debugging, AND passing the updated values back to the view, the update was not happening.

I tested this by passing a random string concatenated to the email address I was testing.
This confirmed that although it appeared the model was being updated with my check it was not the case. Grr.

To solve the issue I instead added an error to the model state, out side of fluent validation:

```
public virtual ActionResult AddCustomer(CustomerAddViewModel model)
{            
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Email))
    {
      var exists = _userService.UserExists(model.Email);
      if (exists) 
      { 
        ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Email Already Exists"); 
       }
    }
}
```

And then just posting the error message as usual using the HTMl Helper :

`@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Email, "", new { @class = "help-block" })`

I don't understand as to why I couldnt affect the model before validation was carried out, but could still see the cahnges when stepping trhough the code, it made this a lot more long winded than it should be.